# Adding/Finding Places for Instructions - Game Library IDA

Tags: ida, assembly, android, arm

Is there any way to add instructions to a library in IDA? My predicament is that there is no room in a game library (.so ELF, android) to fit my own code. There is an empty bss segment but IDA doesn't like to write to it, and I believe the game needs it for it's variables.

I've tried adding additional bytes to the end of the file with a hex editor, and then opening it with IDA, but IDA will not show it possibly because it's not in a segment.

Can I make my own library / modify the existing one so that the code segment is larger? My own library would need to be imported by the other library in order to work, I believe, because it needs functions and such from the original library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDA not the most convenient tool for what you're trying to do. There are basically 3 ways to do it, and it seems you're already mentioning all of them in your question :

- Search for a code cave big enough to fit your payload
- Create a new section in your executable with a sufficient size for your payload
- Proxify your library and add functions or hook existing ones

Now depending on what exactly you're trying to inject and how you're reaching it, each method has its specific pro/cons and will require a different approach. They should all be fairly well documented on the Internet.

(Without more context/details about what you're trying to do, it's hard to tell you which one to pick though)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to create a new section in my executable, but when I do, IDA will not patch the bytes that I put in the section. Is there any way around this? Thanks

Comment: The simplest way would be with either an hex editor or an ELF lib for your favorite language to add a section directly in the ELF header.

Comment: What hex editor would you recommend for this? HxD, I believe, does not support adding sections into the ELF header.

Comment: 010 Editor with an ELF template? But the hex editor is the "quick and dirty" way, do it programatically with a lib would be more reliable.